# Команда /start на перезагрузку

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Есть код, как сделать так, чтобы в нем работала команда /start на перезагрузку?

```
@dp.message_handler(state=UserState.name)
async def get_username(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(username=message.text)
    await message.answer("*Отлично!* Теперь отправь свой адрес электронной почты, куда я продублирую свой ответ и ты его точно не потеряешь! ",parse_mode= "Markdown")
    await UserState.next()  # либо же UserState.adress.set()
    
@dp.message_handler(state=UserState.pochta)
async def get_mail(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(pochta=message.text)
    asa = message.text
    if '@' not in asa:
        await message.answer("Неправильно")

    else:

        await message.answer("*Супер!* Отправь свой номер телефона для того что бы я мог с тобой связаться ",parse_mode= "Markdown")
        await UserState.next()
```

Comment: Попробуй через `await state.set_state(UserState.*название первого состояния*)`

Comment: Что значит `перезагрузку`?

Comment: ну когда в бот,прилетает команда /start,все начинается с начала

Comment: Что такое `всё`? Я вас не понимаю

Comment: Приведите конкретный пример, как и в каком порядке это должно работать

Comment: Спасибо парни,сделал через state="*",теперь когда я ввожу /start ,он перекидывает меня в начало,но все ответы регает по fsm

Answer (score 0):

Если я вас правильно понял, вы хотите чтобы state прерывался при вызове /start

Сделать это можно так:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands='start', state='*') #state='*' означает что на /start бот откликается в любом state
async def start(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):

    await state.finish()

    #выполняем остальные действия
```